# How can I code a dice game add two players name

Tags: python

```
import random

class Dice:
  def roll(self):
    First = random.randit(1, 6)
    Second = random.randint(1, 6)
    return First, second


dice1= Dice()
dice1.roll()
```

Comment: Pls I need answers urgently

Comment: Pls how can I add two players name to it

Comment: Seems you are able to start but not clear what your issue is in completing your code. Have you tried searching on stackoverflow for dice games i.e. web search using **python stackoverflow dice game** to get ideas?  You may benefit from these previous questions & answers.

Comment: Thanks for the info I am new at stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a good description of what you are trying to do here, but based on my assumptions you might want something like this:

```
import random

class Player:
  # initialize a player class with name of player
  def __init__(self, name):
    this.name = name

  # Roll dice method
  def roll(self):
    First = random.randit(1, 6)
    Second = random.randint(1, 6)
    return First, second


player1 = Player("Alice")
player1.roll()
player2 = Player("John")
player2.roll()
```